# transfer variable with button in custom cell iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cell

Hye everybody!! i have a problem that i don't know what can i do!!
My goal is transfer a variable of one TableviewController in other ViewController when i clic in the buttom in customcell. I use a Custom Cell and in the customcell i have 2 label, one buttom. 
this is my code:

ArticlesCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculerViewController.h"
@interface ArticlesCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblproduit;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblargent;
- (IBAction)btnincrement:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *recupererlblproduit;
@end
```

the one tableviewcontroller:

ArticlesTableViewController.m

```
#import "ArticlesTableViewController.h"
#import "ArticlesCell.h"


@interface ArticlesTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ArticlesTableViewController
@synthesize arrayargent1,arrayproduit1,arrayargent2,arrayproduit2,recuperationproduit;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  recuperationproduit=nil;
  arrayproduit1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Câble Ethernet UTP-CAT5 ",@"Câble Ethernet UTP-CAT6 ",@"Carte Réseau",@"Hub",@"Switch",@"Routeur",nil];
  arrayargent1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10 000",@"15 000 ",@"250 000",@"300 000",@"500 000",@"550 000",nil];
  arrayproduit2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ram ",@"Disque Dur",@"Câble d'Alimentation",@"Carte Mere",@"Processeur",nil];
  arrayargent2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"100",@"15 000 ",@"250 000",@"300 000",@"500 000",@"550 000",nil];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 if (section == 0)
    return self.arrayproduit1.count;
 if (section == 1)
    return self.arrayproduit2.count;
 return 0;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (section == 0)
    return @"Matériels Réseaux";
  if (section == 1)
    return @"Matériels Ordinateur";
  return @"undefined";
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguecalcule"])
  {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    CalculerViewController *calculerViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
            calculerViewController.introlblproduit=recuperationproduit;
            calculerViewController.delegate = self;

  }


}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellArticle";



ArticlesCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ArticlesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


if (indexPath.section == 0){
    cell.lblproduit.text = [arrayproduit1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblargent.text = [self.arrayargent1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    cell.lblproduit.text = [self.arrayproduit2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblargent.text = [self.arrayargent2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}  

return cell;
}

- (void)calculerViewControllerDidCancel:(CalculerViewController *)cancel
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}

@end
```

CalculerViewController.m

```
#import "CalculerViewController.h"
@interface CalculerViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalculerViewController
@synthesize display,lbltitre,delegate,introlblproduit;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  lbltitre.text=introlblproduit;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)valider:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {

[self.delegate calculerViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
@end
```

I want to transfer the label of my custom cell when i clic in the buttom.
Help me please!!

Comment: You just want to send the Custom Cell's label value to another viewcontroller. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, when i click on the buttom in the same cell!! thanks for your comment!! it's very important for me to resolve this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to directly connect the button in each cell to the same method in your view controller and then use the sender parameter to access the tapped cell.

Something like this (not tested):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellArticle";

    ArticlesCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[ArticlesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // When the user taps the cell button, fire a method on the view controller
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside];

    ...
}

- (void) cellTapped:(id)sender
{
    ArticleCell *cell = sender.parent; // XXX: This is where it gets ugly!
    // Now send your cell content to your other view controller.
}
```

But as you can see that approach gets **really ugly** in that you have to know about the view hierarchy within the cell.

So, a much better approach is to use the delegate pattern: have the UITableViewCell subclass have a delegate that you connect to your UIViewController instance.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
// Forward declaration required because protocol references class
@protocol ArticlesCellDelegate;

@interface ArticlesCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblproduit;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblargent;
- (IBAction)btnincrement:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *recupererlblproduit;

// New delegate property
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ArticleCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol ArticlesCellDelegate
  - (void) didTapButtonInArticleCell:(ArticleCell*)cell;
@end
```

Then in your view controller:

```
@interface ArticlesTableViewController () <ArticleCellDelegate>

@end

@implementation ArticlesTableViewController

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellArticle";

    ArticlesCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[ArticlesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Make the view controller the cell's delegate
    cell.delegate = self;
    ...
}

- (void) didTapButtonInArticleCell:(ArticleCell*)cell  {

    // Now send your cell content to your other view controller.
}
```

The other thing you need is in your article cell class, you need to handle the delegate when the button is tapped. Your btnIncrement: method can do that:

```
@implementation ArticleCell

...
- (IBAction)btnincrement:(id)sender;
{
    if( self.delegate )
        [self.delegate didTapButtonInArticleCell:self];
}
```

As a side note, if I were you I'd move as many of those UI elements out of the interface definition as I could. The interface section is exactly what it says: a place to define the interface. You usually want to encapsulate the inner workings of your view in the implementation section and have the interface section just reflect the way you want it to be used.

Comment: ok thanks!! i try to resolve my problem with your answer and if i blocke i will post here!!thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I've not tested the code so there might be a few minor nits in it. The approach is correct though.

Comment: it works perfectly!! thank you very much smee!! you have resolved my problem!! i'm very happy to continious my project!! thank you!! :D . i have used your 2nd solution (delegate)

Comment: Great to hear it's working :). Please could you mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in your prepareForSegue method your navigation controller's child view controllers have not been created yet, and reaching into a navigation controller and trying to manipulate it's root view controller is bad design anyway.

I suggest making your navigation controller a custom subclass of UINavigationController. Give it properties to hold your values and set them up in your prepareForSegue.

Then in your CalculerViewController's viewDidLoad, fetch your navigation controller, cast it to your custom class, and read the data from the navigation controller.

Comment: thanks for your answer!! i don't understand, i'm new in Objective-C and iphone!! can you post one example please!!

Comment: I don't have an example, this is unique to your application. I'm not going to write your code for you. What part(s) don't you understand? Read up on that part/those parts. Experiment. If you get stuck, post further questions.

Comment: i can transfer a variable if i use a buttom in navigation controller,i have read a lot of tutorial to do this but my project is a buttom in custom cell!! how can i transfer the label when i click the buttom on the same cell